# results 404 when Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I'm receiving a 404 at `/mini-profiler-resources/results` and after messing around with the request in Fiddler I notice that it only returns a 404 when `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` is sent with the request.

Changing or removing the content type results in a 200 response.

The post that is returning the 404 is being triggered by `includes.js`

I have set up a MiniProfiler handler in my web.config as such:

`<handlers>
      <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>`

Any idea why this only returns a 404 with that content-type set to the above?

**UPDATE**

I have two projects running here and this seems to be causing the 404 issue.

In IIS I have a website pointing to my web application folder, and an application running inside of that which points to my Web API project.

I'm trying to log ajax calls to the web api however this seems to be causing the issue. If I remove calls to `MiniProfiler.Stop()` in the Web API global.asax, the 404 issue goes away. MiniProfiler isn't able to profile ajax requests to the API endpoints however.

My guess is that I need to store the results of the profiling in some central location rather than using the default provider. Calling `Stop` was prematurely killing the MiniProfiler process?

Comment: `UTF-81` 81?? is this on purpose?

Comment: That's a typo on my part. The code tick key is next to the 1. Pressing them simultaneously is a daily occurrence.